# Nginx NodeJS proxying + AngularJS index.html rewriting

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx

I have a webapp built on NodeJS + Express / AngularJS.

AngularJS `$routeProvider` is in `html5` mode, meaning there is no index.html nor # in the URL.

I would like to use nginx to :

- proxy `/api` to my NodeJS app
- redirect all request in `/` to `/index.html`
- redirect all request in `/app` to `/app/index.html`

**Examples**

- `/support`: `/` should be rewrited to `index.html`, then the angular $routeProvider process the `support` route and render `SupportController`
- `/app/login`: `/app/` should be rewrited to `/app/index.html`, then the angular $routeProvider process the `login` route and render `LoginController`
- `/api/auth/login`: `/api/*` should always be proxy redirected to `http://localhost:3000/` cause there's no static file to serve under `/api`

**Constraint**

The problem is, that using something like this to redirect to the API:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri @backend;
}
```

Is not compatible with the AngularJS index.html rewrite:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

location /app/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html =404;
}
```

And if I specify a `/api` location, Nginx overwrite it with the `/` location ...

What can I do here ?

Comment: Why are you `\\ ` before `$`? They are not needed

Comment: Yes ofc I removed them that's because I copied from my bash script so need esscaping in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right configuration, I think I tested it before posting here but as nginx was redirecting `https://example.com/api/login/auth` on `http://locahost:3000/api/login/auth` and not `http://locahost:3000/login/auth`, I was getting 404s from Express, so I thought they came from Nginx ... I'm just "stupid as stupid does" ...

Thanks for your help Tarun !

Here is the good configuration (which is really basic):

```
location /api {
    proxy_set_header  Host \$host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;

    # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;

    proxy_redirect      http://localhost:3000 https://example.com/api/;
}

location / {
    try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.html =404;
}

location /app/ {
    try_files \$uri \$uri/ /app/index.html =404;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be a simple config as such

```
location / {
   try_files /index.html =555;
}

location /app/ {
  try_files /app/index.html =666;
}

location /api/ {
   proxy_pass http://nodeip:3000/;
}
```

If what you explained is right then above config should do

Comment: Yes but I said I need to rewrite every request (like /`support`, or `/app/login`) to the index.html files ... using html5 mode on angularjs

Comment: Add few exact urls and what you expect to your question. Please add arguments also, so i understand

Comment: @SherlockStd, need some time to better understand this. Will get back to you in few days. See if you can solve it yourself by then or someone else pitches in

Comment: Already solved, see my answer below :) thanks for everything !